# segmentation fault in rotating array by D places

Tags: arrays, rotation

In this problem, I am supposed to rotate the array to the left (counter-clockwise) by `D`steps, where `D` is a positive integer. My code works for small inputs but gives a segmentation fault for larger inputs. I tried using a dynamic array by using vectors but somehow the driver code doesn't let me use it, can someone help? , here's the - [CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gye9X.png) and [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQFX7.png) also here are the constraints :

- `N` is the size of the array
- `D` is the number of positions to rotate
- `1 <= N <= 10^6`
- `1 <= D <= 10^6`
- `0 <= arr[i] <= 10^5`

I tried running the code in O(N) Time Complexity, but it gives me segmentation fault for larger inputs

code as text

```
//{ Driver Code Starts
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


// } Driver Code Ends
class Solution{
    public:
    
    //Function to rotate an array by d elements in counter-clockwise direction. 
    void reverse(int arr[], int low, int high)
        {
            while(low<high)
            {
                swap(arr[low], arr[high]);
                low++;
                high--;
            }
        }
    void rotateArr(int arr[], int d, int n){
        // code here
        
        reverse(arr,0,d-1);
        reverse(arr,d,n-1);
        reverse(arr,0,n-1);
    }
};

//{ Driver Code Starts.

int main() {
    int t;
    //taking testcases
    cin >> t;
    
    while(t--){
        int n, d;
        
        //input n and d
        cin >> n >> d;
        
        int arr[n];
        
        //inserting elements in the array
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            cin >> arr[i];
        }
        Solution ob;
        //calling rotateArr() function
        ob.rotateArr(arr, d,n);
        
        //printing the elements of the array
        for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
// } Driver Code Ends
```

Comment: Please post code a text and not as image ...

Comment: Imagine what happens if `D > N` ...

Comment: @derpirscher here it is, i have added the code as text

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h  And also note, that variable-length arrays (ie `int arr[n];`)  are not part of the C++ standard ...